# Database returning undefined results when I query the DB using NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to access data from my MySQL database and compare that data to my form data to authenticate sign in process. But the problem I am facing is that my database query is returning undefined values in the `db.query()` function. I have attached the code of my `index.js` below:

```
app.post("/api/get/signin", (req,res)=>{
    
    const userid = req.body.userId;
    userIdG = userid;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const consumerKey = req.body.consumerKey;
    const sqlSelect =
    `SELECT userid FROM signup WHERE userid = ? AND password = ? AND consumerKey = ?`;
     db.query(sqlSelect,[userid , password , consumerKey], (err, result)=> {
        console.log(result.userid);
        console.log(err);
        //console.log(err);
        if(result.userid == userid && result.password == password && result.consumerKey == consumerKey)
        {
            //res.send(result);
            console.log("Successfully Login");
            auth = true;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Local');
            console.log(userid);
            console.log(password);
            console.log(consumerKey);
            console.log("UnSuccessfully Login");
            auth = false;
        }
         
    })
})
```

[image: Undefined data returned from the database]

Answer (score 2):

`result` will be an array (because queries can have multiple results), so to access the userid (of the first result, provided that there is one!):

```
console.log(result[0].userid)
```